# How to Parse the onemap.sg API response?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I Calling the OneMap.sg API

```
$url='http://www.onemap.sg/API/Services.svc/ga?token=**************&sv=575565';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(curl_error($curl));
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

And get the below response its working perfect.

```
string(0) "" string(109) "{"GeoAddrInfo":[{"BLDG_NAME":"BISHAN PARK SECONDARY SCHOOL","HBRN":"2 SIN MING WALK","PostalCode":"575565"}]}"
```

Now I want to get the value from above response results Like.

```
{

    BLDG_NAME = "BISHAN PARK SECONDARY SCHOOL";

    HBRN      = "2 SIN MING WALK";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [JSON](http://php.net/json_decode), so you can

```
$resp = json_decode($resp);

echo $resp->GeoAddrInfo[0]->BLDG_NAME;
echo $resp->GeoAddrInfo[0]->HBRN;
```